# In Python, how do I make a specific window stay on top?

Tags: python

I have seen a few methods, but none of the work.

```py
import win32gui, win32process, win32con
import os

windowList = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(lambda hwnd, windowList: windowList.append((win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd),hwnd)), windowList)
cmdWindow = [i for i in windowList if "c:\python26\python.exe" in i[0].lower()]
win32gui.SetWindowPos(cmdWindow[0][1],win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,100,100,0) #100,100 is the size of the window
'''
This one doens't work because the range exceeds the list.

'''
import win32gui
import win32con

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd,win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,100,100,200,200,0)
```

This one works as in it stays on top, but not the window I want.

Is there a line I could add so it knows which window I want? Or is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`win32gui.FindWindow`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__FindWindow_meth.html)

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Untitled - Notepad')
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd,win32con.HWND_TOPMOST,100,100,200,200,0)
```